# Can I make my distribution database use In-Memory OLTP?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to have all the distribution tables use In-Memory OLTP (formerly known as Hekaton) for enhancing performance of the distribution database?

Have you tried it?

Did that increase the overall performance when the distribution database was the bottleneck for your replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have all the distribution tables use In-Memory OLTP (formerly known as Hekaton) for enhancing performance of the distribution database?

This is a good question and made me thinking. But .... the answer is NO as of SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.0.

The [documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600379.aspx) :

> Replication tables on the distributor cannot be configured as memory-optimized tables.

Comment: Dang!  I really appreciate your answer and research, though.  This would have been a lifesaver in some cases!

Comment: Hekaton is getting matured .. so stay tuned so good improvements and support in future versions of sql server.